# Spring Boot unable to use messageSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, resourcebundle

I am currently working on translating a Spring Boot application for my company. After a short time on Google I found several guides and which seemed to be what I needed. It build a small test application and it worked, but when I tried to transfer the code to the main application I now get a "NoSuchMessageException".

Google turned up more guides and other StackOverflow questions but nothing, that was suggested, worked. Currently I'm at the end of my knowledge and hope that, maybe someone encountered this problem too and knows a fix.

This is the method I call with postman, where I expect the translation:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource

@GetMapping("/teststub")
    public String test() {
        return messageSource.getMessage("hello.world", null, Locale.GERMAN);
    }
```

And with here I have registered the MessageSource Bean:

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

The messageSource bundle is located in:

```
resources
| other_folders
| messages.properties
| messages_de.properties
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>an api</description>
    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <!-- To replace placeholders in sonar-project.properties -->
                    <include>sonar-project.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>config/**</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <argLine>
                        ${surefireArgLine}
                    </argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.repository}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: what does `messages_de.properties` contain?

Comment: ```messages_de.properties:
hello.world=Hallo Welt
```    

``` messages.properties:
hello.world=Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while getting the message source it needs the proper path else MessageBundle doesnt get configured properly.

i would suggest to try

```
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
```

if messages is in root path

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem.

In the pom.xml is a resource definition which excludes everything from the resources-folder except for the config subfolder.
After changing this definition everything works as expected.

-.-